# how to pass id in url after click on signin button in django and go to user dashboard page

Tags: django-views, django-urls

how to pass id in url after click on signin button in django, dashboard change accorrding signin id ,which id pass in url. I am trying to pass id in url,when user click on signin button.if another user signin then pass that user id in url.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as soon as  the button is clicked, the user is redirected to the home page and the user_id is also passed in the URL .